# How to include test dependencies in sbt-assembly jar?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am unable to package my test dependencies in my test assembly jar. Here is an excerpt from my `build.sbt`:

```
...

name := "project"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

assemblyOption in (Compile, assembly) := (assemblyOption in (Compile, assembly)).value.copy(includeScala = false)

fork in Test := true

parallelExecution in IntegrationTest := false

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).configs(IntegrationTest.extend(Test)).settings(Defaults.itSettings: _ *)

Project.inConfig(Test)(baseAssemblySettings)

test in (Test, assembly) := {}

assemblyOption in (Test, assembly) := (assemblyOption in (Test, assembly)).value.copy(includeScala = false, includeDependency = true)

assemblyJarName in (Test, assembly) := s"${name.value}-test.jar"

fullClasspath in (Test, assembly) := {
  val cp = (fullClasspath in Test).value
  cp.filter{ file => (file.data.name contains "classes") || (file.data.name contains "test-classes")}  ++  (fullClasspath in Runtime).value
}

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.10" % "test" excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "joda-time"),
  ...
)

...
```

When I assemble my fat jar using `sbt test:assembly`, is produces the fat jar `project-test.jar`, but the `play-json` dependencies aren't being packaged in:

```
$ jar tf /path/to/project-test.jar | grep play
$
```

However, if I remove the `"test"` configuration from the `play-json` dep (i.e. `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.10" excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "joda-time")`), I can see it being included:

```
$ jar tf /path/to/project-test.jar | grep play
...
play/libs/Json.class
...
$
```

Am I doing anything wrong and/or missing anything? My goal here is to include the `play-json` library in ONLY the `test:assembly` jar and NOT the `assembly` jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have left out a crucial part in the original `build.sbt` excerpt I posted above which turned out to be the cause of the issuse:

```
fullClasspath in (Test, assembly) := {
  val cp = (fullClasspath in Test).value
  cp.filter{ file => (file.data.name contains "classes") || (file.data.name contains "test-classes")}  ++  (fullClasspath in Runtime).value
}
```

This code block was essentially filter out deps from the test classpath. We include this to avoid painful merge conflicts. I fixed this by adding logic to include the `play-json` dep that was needed:

```
fullClasspath in (Test, assembly) := {
  val cp = (fullClasspath in Test).value
  cp.filter{ file =>
    (file.data.name contains "classes") ||
    (file.data.name contains "test-classes") ||
    // sorta hacky
    (file.data.name contains "play")
  }  ++  (fullClasspath in Runtime).value
}
```